# MariaDB CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default

Tags: mysql, date, default, mariadb

I'm trying to set up a DB for user registration and in want to have a column with the registration date in it, which should be the current time by default. I tried running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  <some stuff>
  `uRegDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

But it doesn't work with MariaDB. Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 13):

What if you change the datatype to [`TIMESTAMP`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/) instead of `DATETIME` like

```
`uRegDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Right, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default for `DATETIME` type is only available in 10.x. If you're using 5.5, it should a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **MariaDB 10.1.12** and your statement works for me.

```
create table datetest (
 date1 datetime default current_timestamp,
 date2 timestamp default current_timestamp);
insert into datetest values ( );
```

The above statements execute without any error and the following result is displayed

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| date1               | date2               |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-11-29 17:16:58 | 2016-11-29 17:16:58 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```